# Using array_push to add elements to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array & I'd like to add data to the array using PHP. I can't add it directly.

How would I do this using [array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var parks = [{"title":"Football Park","lat":"55.86234","lng":"-4.250635999999986","img":"icon.png"}]
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript is clientside scripting and PHP is server side scripting. Not possible like this.

Comment: First json decode it. Add an item. Than json encode it.

Comment: @Michal-sk웃 - can you possibly show me an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
//if your JSON string on server side <--PHP-->
    $park = json_decode([{"title":"Football Park","lat":"55.86234","lng":"-4.250635999999986","img":"icon.png"}],true);
    $park['key'] = 'someValue';
    $newJSON = json_encode($park);

// if your JSON string on client side <--JS-->
var parkObj = JSON.parse(park);
parkObj.key = 'someValue';
console.log(JSON.stringify(parkObj));
//[{"title":"Football Park","lat":"55.86234","lng":"-4.250635999999986","img":"icon.png","key" : "someValue"}]
```

Comment: Thanks - will give this a try just now :-)

Answer (score -1):

I found http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php and feel this will do the job for me - thanks for your input.